# How to plot a truncated normal distribution with known paramters, in R

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, truncated

I would like to generate a truncated normal distribution with known parameters in either R. Note that the I'm not seeking a pseudo-random number generator.

Assume that I have a normal distribution with mean 5 and standard deviation of 1. Can I plot the values of a truncated normal distribution, truncated at points 1 and 10?

Comment: Are you talking about the `truncnorm` package? The `dtruncnorm` function gives the density

Comment: Hi @juan. Yes, i'm talking about the truncnorm package. I've tried the dtruncnorm function but it doesn't seem to give the density. For example if I enter the code: `vec=seq(from=0,by=0.01,length.out = 100)
test=dtruncnorm(vec, a=0,b=1,mean=0.1,sd=0.1)
plot(test)` then I get a plot which has the exact shape of a truncated normal distribution, and the x-values are accurate. However, the y-axis ranges from 0 to 5. This means that it is not showing the densities (they should all be less than 1)

Comment: If the y-axis range goes above 1 it does **not** mean that it isn't a density. It's the integral over the space (or R, the real line) that must be equal to 1.

Comment: @user5211911 Why do you think density values must be below one? They are not probabilities, and can be greater than 1 (or even infinite).

Comment: @juan: a large value `y` times a (very) small base may be a really small number...

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry, I should have tagged OP ;-)

Comment: Here's a nice [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163938/83532), part of a good discussion about interpreting density values.

Comment: hey @RuiBarradas, thanks for the clarification. So then what are the densities defined as? I understood them to be the probability of the particular domain element occuring. Or maybe a better question is: how do i convert the "densities" to probabilities?

Comment: hey @juan, thanks for the clarification. So then what are the densities defined as? I understood them to be the probability of the particular domain element occuring. Or maybe a better question is: how do i convert the "densities" to probabilities?

Comment: hold on, i'm reading the example from @juan quickly for a refresher

Comment: @user5211911 A probability density function is 1) a non-negative function 2) whose integral over R is 1 (univariate case). Their values can be greater than 1. Example: the uniform on the interval [0, 1/2] takes the constant value 2. The integral is just the area of a rectangle, 1/2 * 2 == 1.

Comment: Okay I've read the example given by @juan above. I realize that i don't have much experience dealing with density values. Hence may I ask how do I convert densities to ordinary probabilities? Do I just solve the equation x*(sum of all density values)=1?

Comment: Okay I've converted the density to a normal probability distribution by dividing each density value by the sum of all the density values. Resulting distribution would be the probabilities and they all sum to one. Thanks so much for the help guys, I think this works

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

This can be done using the dtruncnorm function from the truncnorm package as suggested previously by juan. I'll demonstrate this using the example in the question of a normal distribution with mean 5, standard deviation of 1 and limits of 1 and 10.

First you must create a vector of the number of points to plot from the distribution, that will be equally spaced. So for example, if you wanted to plot ten points from the distribution equally spaced, your vector ("vec") would be:

```
vec=seq(from=1,by=1,length.out = 10)
```

The above will ensure that we plot 10 points starting from 1, incrementing by 1, up to value 10.

We then put these in the dtruncnorm() function and save it in the "test" variable, and then plot it:

```
test=dtruncnorm(vec,a=1,b=10,mean=5,sd=1)
plot(test)
```

As you see, this plots the density at discrete points. You could easily try and make the plot continuous by increasing the number of points:

```
vec=seq(from=1,by=0.1,length.out = 100)
test=dtruncnorm(vec,a=1,b=10,mean=5,sd=1)
plot(test)
```

Please comment if you have any questions

Answer (score 3):

The following function generates (pseudo) random numbers for any distribution as long as you have both 'd' and 'p' functions available. In `R` parlance this means you must have `dnorm` and `pnorm`, which you do, they're part of base `R`.

```
#
# random numbers for truncated distribution
#
rtrunc <- function(n, distr, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, ...){
    makefun <- function(prefix, FUN, ...){
        txt <- paste(prefix, FUN, "(x, ...)", sep = "")
        function(x, ...) eval(parse(text = txt))
    }
    if(length(n) > 1) n <- length(n)
    pfun <- makefun("p", distr, ...)
    qfun <- makefun("q", distr, ...)
    lo <- pfun(lower, ...)
    up <- pfun(upper, ...)
    u <- runif(n, lo, up)
    qfun(u, ...)
}

# Example:
x <- rtrunc(1, "norm", lower = 0, mean = 2, sd = 5)
```

Comment: hey @rui, this generates pseudo random no.s but does not give the density. I wouldn't like random numbers from the distribution, I need to be able to choose any value in the sample space of the truncated norm. dist. and then to get the respective density for that value.

Comment: For the density, see the comment by juan above, and my answer to your answer.